# The length of the smallest possible ladder to change the bulb.

Tags: calculus, geometry

[image]

In the drawing, the point P, a bit located under the bulb, has coordinates (a, b​​), where a and b are two parameters. You want to change the bulb, and for this it is necessary to install a ladder such that

1. It relies on the ground (the $Ox$) axis at the point $S$.
2. It rests against the vertical wall (the $Oy$ axis) at the point $M$.
3. She passes exactly through the point $P$.

> Question : What, in function of $a$ and $b$ only, the length of the smallest possible ladder fulfilling the three conditions above?

My try: 
I tried to compute the coordinate of $M(0,y_M)$ in function of $a,b$ but I am stuck with some ugly calculs.
I wrote $\Vert\overrightarrow{MS}\Vert=\Vert\overrightarrow{MP}\Vert+\Vert\overrightarrow{PS}\Vert$ and square it. It looks like 
$$
2by_M=a^2-b^2+b^2+(c-a)^2+2\sqrt{a^2(c-a)^2+(ab)^2+b^2(b-y_M)^2+(b-y_M)^2(c-a)^2}
$$

As usual, I think I miss something.

Comment: I assume scale=ladder?

Comment: @DanielRust Oops, yes. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\theta$ be the angle at $S$.  The lower part of the ladder has length $b/\sin\theta$, and the upper part has length $a/\cos\theta$.  Then differentiate the full length with respect to $\theta$.

You want to minimize $b/\sin\theta+a/\cos\theta$, so $b\cos\theta/\sin^2\theta=a\sin\theta/\cos^2\theta$

Comment: So $tan\theta = \sqrt[3]{b/a}$, bizarre though it seems.

Comment: 'The lower part of the ladder has length $b/sin(\theta)$ what did you use to see this ?

Comment: @Yass: $\sin\theta = b/PS$ so $PS = b/\sin\theta$.

Comment: @TonyK I was thinking that relation is only valid when the triangle is right-angled.

Comment: @Yass: Drop a perpendicular from $P$ to the $x$-axis, and you will have yourself a right-angled triangle.

Comment: @TonyK Right, silly me. Thanks. Now we have $tan(\theta)=\frac{MO}{SO}$ and the newt step : I use Pythagorean theorem, right ?

Comment: I got it I think, I have $MS=\frac{y_M}{c}=(\frac{b}{a})^\frac{1}3$, then $MS=c\sqrt{\frac{b}{a})^\frac{1}3+1}$.

Comment: I like this method best; you have $f(\theta)=a\sec\theta+b\csc\theta$ so $f^{\prime}(\theta)=a\sec\theta\tan\theta-b\csc\theta\cot\theta=a\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos^{2}\theta}-b\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^{2}\theta}=0$ when $\frac{a \sin \theta}{\cos^{2}\theta}=\frac{b\cos\theta}{\sin^{2}\theta}$, so $a\sin^{3}\theta=b\cos^{3}\theta$ and $\tan^{3}\theta=\frac{b}{a}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the base of the triangle and let $y$ be the height.
To minimize the length $L$ of the ladder, we can minimize $L^2=x^2+y^2$.

By similar triangles, $\displaystyle\frac{y}{x}=\frac{b}{x-a}$, so $\displaystyle y=\frac{bx}{x-a}$ and $\displaystyle f(x)=L^2=x^2+\frac{b^2x^2}{(x-a)^2}$.

Then $f^{\prime}(x)=2x+\frac{(x-a)^2(2b^{2}x)-b^{2}x^2(2(x-a))}{(x-a)^4}=2x-\frac{2ab^{2}x}{(x-a)^3}=0$ if $2x(x-a)^3=2ab^{2}x$,

so $(x-a)^3=ab^2$ since $x\ne0$.  Therefore $x=a+a^{1/3}b^{2/3}=a^{1/3}(a^{2/3}+b^{2/3})$ and

$\displaystyle \;\;\;\;y=\frac{bx}{x-a}=\frac{ba^{1/3}(a^{2/3}+b^{2/3})}{a^{1/3}b^{2/3}}=b^{1/3}(a^{2/3}+b^{2/3}).$

Now find $L=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your method (It's late here..). Juste one question please what formula did you use when you said $By similar triangles$ : For me a similar triangles is just a definition. I don't know any property about their lengths. (+1 anyway)

Comment: I was using that the height divided by the base for the large triangle is the same as the height divided by the base for the small triangle (which has its height going from the x-axis to the point (a,b)).